# Why ssh-copy-id requires private key file

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

The `ssh-copy-id` was very useful for sending public keys to server. But it fail if you haven't private key file, now.

```
$ ssh-copy-id -i my_friend_rsa.pub root@example.com

/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: failed to open ID file 'my_friend_rsa': No such file
```

I don't understand this behaviour.

There are two cases for me:

1. I send my own public key
2. I send colleague's public key.

The first case is rare. The server has my public key already if I can connect to it. So I don't need the `ssh-copy-id` in this case.

The second case is very often. I grant access to other user. But I have not his nor her private key. So this behaviour makes the ssh-copy-id useless in second case.

Please, explain me why `ssh-copy-id` requires private key file?

Comment: A nitpick, the server can't have your public key first time you connect.

Comment: IMO, while `ssh-copy-id` is somewhat useful in the common case, it isn't useful in all cases.  Just copy and add the keys manually?

Comment: @Fredi can if somebody put it here

Comment: Zoredache, I cant do it manually for single server. But for a lot of servers  I want tool. So `ssh-copy-id` was this tool. But it is broken now. I want to understand the reason

Comment: Use your configuration management system for this. ssh-copy-id really only covers the first case, sending your own keys.

Answer (score 5):

Because of the way this program works. Citing `man ssh-copy-id`:

> ssh-copy-id is a script that uses ssh(1) to log into a remote machine (presumably using a login password, so password authentication should be enabled, unless you've done some clever use of multiple identities).  It assembles a list of one or more finger‐
>        prints (as described below) and tries to log in with each key, to see if any of them are already installed (of course, if you are
>        not using ssh-agent(1) this may result in you being repeatedly prompted for pass-phrases).  It then assembles a list of those that
>        failed to log in, and using ssh, enables logins with those keys on the remote server.

I would agree that this can be too clever sometimes, but this is not the place to ask "why" as we are not the developers.

Answer (score 4):

It needs the private key to verify, that the public key was installed properly (this is basically a sanity check). But ...

You can use the `-f` switch, which will allow you to copy just a public key to the server and will not validate that (**if you have new enough openssh installed**).

It is how the `ssh-copy-id` used to work before. The other possibility is the environment variable `SSH_COPY_ID_LEGACY` which allows you to restore this behavior:

```
$ SSH_COPY_ID_LEGACY=1 ssh-copy-id -i my_friend_rsa.pub root@example.com
```

Or you can just pick up current version of `ssh-copy-id` to use from [upstream repository](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/contrib/ssh-copy-id), which supports the `-f` switch.

Comment: Thanks but is not work for me:

      /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: invalid option (-f)

Comment: If you have new enough openssh. You can always update (modified answer) or use `SSH_COPY_ID_LEGACY` environment variable if you are using RHEL (modified the answer).

Answer (score 0):

As a windows user, I can say it's a shame we don't have the `ssh-copy-id` script. But if you spend some time studying its internals, you might learn that it can be easily replaced with the following command:

```
grep ^AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/ssh/sshd_config | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I{} sh -c 'ssh-add -L >> {}; sort -u {} -o {}';echo  "ForwardAgent yes" >~/.ssh/config
```

Just issue this command right after your login & next time you can authorize by your key, easy as that. If for some reason it won't work for you, please describe your system a little bit in comments. Remember that your ssh-client must be configured to use an agent, forward & password for this command to work. Here is [putty settings screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pp5p7.png).

P.S. In case you might wonder, it works linux -> linux too...